# Select all checkboxes with one check with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to check one checkbox (checkAll) and select all and if I deselect it all should be deselected too. Additionally, if they are all selected and then I uncheck 'a', 'b' or 'c', 'checkAll' also need to be unchecked.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" id="checkAll">
<input type="checkbox" value="a">
<input type="checkbox" value="b">
<input type="checkbox" value="c">
```

What's the trigger I need to use? Tried but failed:

```
$("#checkAll").click(function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event. When the `#checkAll` box is changed, change the other boxes correspondingly.

To change the `#checkAll` box when according to the others, you could do something like this:

```
$(":checkbox").not("#checkAll").change(function()
{
    $("#checkAll").attr("checked", $(":checkbox").not(":checked").not("#checkAll").length ? false : true);
});
```

Basically this will execute when a checkbox other than `#checkAll` changes, and change `#checkAll` depending on whether or not there are unchecked boxes.

Answer (score 2):

Simple script that does what you want:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" id="checkAll">
    <input type="checkbox" value="a" class="others">
    <input type="checkbox" value="b" class="others">
    <input type="checkbox" value="c" class="others">
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#checkAll").change(function() {
        $(":checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked);
    });
    $(".others").change(function() {
        if (!$('input.others[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').length)
            $("#checkAll").attr('checked', true);
        if (!$('input.others[type=checkbox]:checked').length)
            $("#checkAll").attr('checked', false);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This works to check and uncheck all checkboxes if I click "checkAll". However, if all are checked and I uncheck of of the "others" it should also uncheck "checkAll". Also if "checkAll" is not selected and I mannually select all "others" it should select "checkAll". Sorry, it sounds convoluted a bit.

Comment: This works fine for me. What brower and jquery version are you using? Do you use the script multiple times? (in this case, it doesn't work, but i can rearange it to work.)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't change any of your code and it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9U2aQ/

Make sure that you're referencing your jquery file correctly.

Comment: This 'answer' does not address @santa's needs at all. I'd downvote if I had votes left today.

Comment: @santa's need is to understand why his/her code isn't working. I have verified that the code works and provided a recommendation as to why it's not working in his/her environment.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    $(':checkbox').not('#checkAll').change(function()
    {
        $("#checkAll").attr("checked", $(":checkbox").not(":checked").not("#checkAll").length ? false : true);
    }); 
    $("#checkAll").change(function() 
    {
        $(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
```